# Problem with adocom used in old version of vb

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project and had to refer to a already completed project.While  going through[enter image description here][1] it I encountered a problem and wasn't able to understand the code
I want to know what is adosetup doing. 
Msmt_system is table name
While msmt_sys_desc and msmt_sys_val are columns in msmt_system
dbcBoLC is datacombobox

How does datacombo know from which table to access data?

```
Call adoSetup(AdoCom, "Msmt_System", True, dbcBoLC, "Msmt_Sys_Desc", 
     "Msmt_Sys_val")
Call dbcBoLC_Click(1)

'in another file:
Public Sub adoSetup(adoCtrl As Adodc, sRecSrc As String, 
           bLinkAdoCtrl As Boolean, 
           Optional dCombo As DataCombo, 
           Optional sListField As String, 
           Optional sBoundCol As String)

   'Added On: 25/07/2003
   sAppPath = App.Path & "\MultiGauging.mdb"    'Store the Application Path
   sDbConn_String = "DBQ=" & sAppPath & ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};pwd=*****;UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;"

   'Begin: Setup the connection string and apply to datacontrol
   With adoCtrl
     .ConnectionString = sDbConn_String
     .RecordSource = sRecSrc
     .Refresh
   End With
   'End: Setup the connection string and apply to datacontrol

   'Begin: Setup the corresponding combo box
   If bLinkAdoCtrl Then
     Set dCombo.RowSource = adoCtrl
     dCombo.ListField = sListField
     dCombo.BoundColumn = sBoundCol

     If Not (adoCtrl.Recordset.EOF Or adoCtrl.Recordset.BOF) Then
        adoCtrl.Recordset.MoveFirst
        dCombo.BoundText = adoCtrl.Recordset(sBoundCol)
     End If
   End If
   'End: Setup the corresponding combo box
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post data as an image; it isn't helpful to the volunteers your are asking to help you. Post data as formatted text, or even better post it as DDL and DML statements

Comment: `adoSetup` appears to be a `Sub` within your program.  None of us can tell you what it is doing without seeing the code.

Comment: @tgolisch Yaa I found a adosetup sub it was in some other form in the project.

Comment: 'Public Sub adoSetup(adoCtrl As Adodc, sRecSrc As String, bLinkAdoCtrl As Boolean, Optional dCombo As DataCombo, Optional sListField As String, Optional sBoundCol As String)'

Comment: Can u tell me what does it do? And how is it related to the the code i have posted in question

Comment: You only showed the declaration of that Sub.  Please update your question to include the rest of the code from `adoSetup`. Clearly, we won't be able to tell you about a sub that someone wrote, without seeing the code.

Comment: @tgolisch I have added the code please refer to it and lemme know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your call:

```
Call adoSetup(AdoCom, "Msmt_System", True, dbcBoLC, . . .
```

The table name is the 2nd argument. That is how it knows which table (recordsource) to use.  Your sub `adoSetup` just establishes a connection (`ConnectionString = sDbConn_String`) queries a table (`RecordSource = sRecSrc`) then it attaches the data to a combo box (arg 4 to this sub: `dbcBoLC`). The datacombo just uses whatever table was set in `adoCtrl`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Please mark it as "answered", if you are satisfied. Thx

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: To the left of my answer is a zero with an up & down arrow.  Next to that, is a shadow for a check-mark.  If you click it, the checkmark turns green (and I get a few reputation points as a reward).  https://stackoverflow.com/tour